# Weird behaviour of MD5 hash implemented by L Peter Deutsch in C

Tags: c, md5, hash

I am using an MD5 implementation in C done by [L Peter Deutsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_Peter_Deutsch) found from the [page](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~mabzug1/cs/md5/md5.html) and source code from [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmd5-rfc/files/libmd5-rfc/2002-04-13/).

The code in the `main` function of the `md5main.c` file has been modified for my use as follows:

```
md5_byte_t *result = malloc ( 16 );  // Allocating 128 bits.
char data[] = "my name is aman";
md5_state_t state;  // This is a state object used by the MD5 library to do "stuff".
                    // Just treat it as a black box.
md5_init(&state);
md5_append(&state, (const md5_byte_t *)data, strlen(data));
md5_finish(&state, result);
print_bits(result, 128);

md5_append(&state, (const md5_byte_t *)data, strlen(data));
md5_finish(&state, result);
print_bits(result, 128);
//puts(usage);
return 0;
```

The print bits function is as follows:

```
void print_bits ( void * data, int length )
{
    uint8_t *temp_data = (uint8_t *)data;
    int bytes = length>>3;
    printf ("[");
    int i;
    //printf("\nprinting bloom filter\n\n");
    for ( i=0; i<bytes; ++i )
    {
        int j;
        for ( j=sizeof(uint8_t)*8-1; j>=0; --j)
        {
            int l = temp_data[i]>>j & 1;
            printf( "%d", l);
        }
    }
    //printf("\n end printing bloom filter\n\n");
    printf ("]\n");
}
```

You will need to include `stdlib.h` and the code.

Now for the string the `my name is aman`, it produced two different hash values when called two times. It produced the following on my system:

```
[01110000100000100110101111101101000011000100011100110111010100110010011100110011111100100111100100100011101011000111110011010101]
[11101001101110101111000010101100000000011011010110110011111001111010110111001011000001010000010111000010101111101101000010011000]
```

What is the reason for this weird behavior? Was it not supposed to produce the same hash value for a particular key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `md5_init` again after the first call to `md5_finish`.